# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A5077 when excute crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i get error `0x800A5077`, i try import `CrystalActiveXReportViewerLib10` and `CrystalReportsCommonObjectModelLib`, but it still no work.

```
Call ReportConnection(CInspAuditList, "Pab_Prod")
        CInspAuditList.ReportFileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\MAuditList.rpt"
        Call SubReportConnection(CInspAuditList, "Pab_Prod")
        CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(0, "mchno; " & frmMachine.machine & " ;true")
        CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(1, "batch; " & CDbl(frmMachine.batch) - 1 & " ;true")
        CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(2, "Points; " & InpStdPt & " ;true")
        CInspAuditList.set_ParameterFields(3, "ovrpt; " & OvrPoints & " ;true")
        CInspAuditList.Action = 1
```

the error occur when `CInspAuditList.Action = 1`

vb.net help me declare `CInspAuditList as AxCrystal.AxCrystalReport` 
This is my function for connection:

```
Public Function ReportConnection(ByRef CrystalReport1 As AxCrystal.AxCrystalReport, ByRef dsnname As String) As Boolean
        CrystalReport1.Connect = "dsn=" & dsnname & ";UID=" & gstrID & ";PWD=" & gstrPassword & ";DSQ="
    End Function
```

I want to know the reason cause the error happen & my connection correct or not

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me and that is because the report file (.rpt) contains a connection to a database that doesn't exists or cannot be located by the computer where you are running the program solution: open the report file (.rpt), menu database, verify database, checkout the parameters of the connection(mine is sql connection), ok, and you can see a msg that say the database is up to date, ok, save changes in report

Answer (score 0):

If you ara using system dsn, crystal report needs admin rights for connect.
In the registry ODBC key is Local Machine and only grant Full Control to System and Administrators.